# How to scrape text in a href by Beautiful Soup?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I have a href in format `<a href="javascript:ShowImg('../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg');">`, and I want to get the url with `'../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg'`. I used a stupid way to get it:( I want to know if there is a more easier way to get it.

```
url = '<a href="javascript:ShowImg('../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg');">'
html = url.get('href')
html = html.replace('javascript:ShowImg(', '').replace(');', '')
```

The original tag as below:

```
<a href="javascript:ShowImg('../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg');">
<img height="110" onerror="this.src='../UploadFile/Images/no_pic_big.jpg';"
src="../UploadFile/Images/c/1/S_27902.jpg" width="170"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` can apply a [compiled regular expression pattern](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) to attribute values when searching for elements. You then can use the same pattern to extract the desired part of it:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<a href="javascript:ShowImg('../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg');">
<img height="110" onerror="this.src='../UploadFile/Images/no_pic_big.jpg';"
src="../UploadFile/Images/c/1/S_27902.jpg" width="170"/>
</a>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
pattern = re.compile(r"javascript:ShowImg\('(.*?)'\);")

href = soup.find('a', href=pattern)["href"]
link = pattern.search(href).group(1)
print(link)  # prints ../UploadFile/Images/c/1/B_27902.jpg
```

Comment: I tried your code, but `soup.find('a', href=pattern)` return `None`, what's wrong?

Comment: @mikezang this one also works for me. Are you sure you have this `a` element in the input data you are parsing with `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: I think it is no problem, but I an not sure why that I couldn't do it. By the way, I am using Python3.5. http://www.brickshelf.com/gallery/mikezang/pics/screenshot_2016-03-05_23.45.29.jpg

Comment: @mikezang watch the `r` prefix before the pattern string - it is important.

Comment: There is a r prefix in code, I copied all your code without any modified!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105441/discussion-between-alecxe-and-mikezang).

Comment: @mikezang btw, here is a complete working code (using the real link you provided): https://gist.github.com/alecxe/5bc3e14a2f13c21f16f3.

Comment: I tried your code, it is ok! I have two questions: 1. I didn't use requests, does this make difference? 2. how to parse more than one links?

Comment: @mikezang updated the gist to extract multiple links..requests should not make the difference, but I'd still stick to it - it makes things easier - http for humans :)

Comment: I found reason! check my question, I parse with tag 'a' so that find('a') return None, how can I use RegExp in get('href')?

Comment: I got it! Use  `link = pattern.search(href).group(1)` instead my  `html = html.replace('javascript:ShowImg(', '').replace(');', '')`